# Windows 10 won't connect to open Wi-Fi network if I don't use USB Wi-Fi Adapter

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I am trying to connect to an open Wi-Fi network, but somehow Windows 10 does not allow it, and I get the following message:

`Can't connect to this network`

Sometimes I manage to connect (after many trials), but in that case it says `No internet`

I even formatted and reinstalled Windows 10, but nothing.

I can use my phone to connect to the open Wi-Fi network without any problem. I can also connect any other device.

Finally I could connect my laptop to the open Wi-Fi network by using an USB Wi-Fi Adapter. Is there a good explanation?

I guess it's related to the Wi-Fi device driver, but I don't have any problem to connect my laptop to another open Wi-Fi network.

Comment: You are on the money as far as it being the device driver for that specific adapter.  Knowing WHAT adapter sure might help.  Could it have to do with what you have NAMED your SSID?  Perhaps it is the security you have chosen for it.  SOMETHING (as you know) is different about it.  You should chase the Wifi end and not the device end (it will be much easier to solve).